# Reading random length of characters at a time

Tags: c#, .net, string, console-application

I'm trying to read a series of characters that are typed in at a time, on a console application:

```
  while(true)
  {     
    var input= string.Empty;
    do
    {
        var key = Console.ReadKey();    
        input += key.KeyChar;              
    }
    while (input.Length <= 5);

    //do something with input.
  }
```

Since there will be no carriage return, I could make this work by putting a fixed length for the input. But actually I won't know how many characters will be entered at a time...it could be anywhere from 1 - 10. Is there anyway to modify the above code so that the app can take in whatever is entered at a time? The only thing that separates different inputs is time (at least 2 or 3 seconds can be assumed), since there is no carriage return.

Comment: *The only thing that separates different inputs is time (at least 2 or 3 seconds can be assumed)* That seems like a pretty horrible design. If you are going to be relying on some random time interval, this is going to be a headache.

Comment: @MattBurland I agree :) Currently working with some limitations, so this is just a temp solution (if at all possible).

Comment: @Prabhu, possible, but certainly not worth it.

Comment: If it's a barcode scanner, you can configure those to send an Enter (either CR, LF or both) after the code.

Comment: @CodeCaster from comments (on my deleted answer) it is a RFID reader, but ususally you can configure them just the same.

Comment: Why, may I ask, do you not what to use a carriage return? It seems to me that it would accomplish the task with way less effort.

Comment: @AlexanderLindsay because the RFID scan is not sending in the carriage return.

Comment: @Prabhu that makes sense. Maybe you could read in all the chars as you get them and record the time received and then process later? Though I could see that running into the problem of when to process.

Comment: Check the manual for your RFID reader because I find it hard to believe that it doesn't send *something* as a start and/or end of message marker. It maybe the case you need to read *bytes* from it rather than a string. So you'll wait for some control byte, then read bytes until you get some stop value and then the bytes you've read can be converted to a string.

Comment: For example [this RFID reader](http://www.robotshop.com/media/files/PDF/users-manual-rfid-idr-232n.pdf) appears to send an `0x01` (SOH) and then an `0x02` (STX) with the ascii code in-between. Your device probably does something similar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So as horrible an idea as I think using a timeout to decide whether or not a user is done, you could achieve it with something like this:

```
var input = string.Empty;
var lockObj = new Object();
System.Threading.Timer timer = new System.Threading.Timer(o =>
{
    string localInput;
    lock(lockObj)
    {
        localInput = input;
        input = string.Empty;
    }
    Console.WriteLine("\noutput: {0}", localInput);

}, null, System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite, System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite);   
while (true)
{
    var key = Console.ReadKey();
    timer.Change(2000, System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite);
    lock(lockObj)
    {
        input += key.KeyChar;
    }
}
```

You start a timer (cancelling any previous one) when a key is pressed and when that timer expires (assuming it wasn't cancelled by another key press), you do something with whatever value is currently in `input`. Note: since you are now multithreading, you will need to worry about what that *something* you are doing is and whether or not it's thread-safe. You may have to lock or synchronize.

Comment: Please use some synchronization or interlocked operation.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Agreed, but since I don't know what they are actually doing, it may be beyond the scope of the question.

Comment: How about `Console.WriteLine("\noutput: {0}", Interlocked.Exchange(ref input, string.Empty));` ?  (Fixing the append is slightly more difficult, requiring an CMPX loop or use locking for both)

Comment: Updated, it was just easier to do a lock around the critical sections instead of trying to `Interlocked.Exchange`

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: Thanks, that's about what I was thinking too.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks for all the help. Quite ingenious.